# How can I assert a cell value in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing pytest unit test cases where the call returns a Pandas Dataframe and I want to assert a particular cell value in it. I tried this but throws me `E       ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

```
assert result_df.loc[result_df['col_A'].str.contains('A_val') and result_df['col_B'].str.contains('2018-05-13'), 'col_C'].item() == 'Q3'
```

Here is my sample data:

```
    id   col_A      col_B  
0  RK7   A_val    2018-05-13                  
1  RK7   A_val    2018-09-02                   
0  BM    A1_val   2018-05-05                    
1  BM    A1_val   2018-05-05                      

          col_C  
0         Q3  
1         Q4  
0         Q1 
1         Q2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, with date time series I need to convert using `strftime` and not just `str`.
Here is the correct one:

```
check1 = result_df['col_A'].str.contains('A_val')
check2 = result_df['col_B'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).str.contains('2018-05-13')
assert result_df.loc[check1 & check2]['col_C'].item() == '2018-Q3-COST'
```

Thanks @wpercy for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `and` keyword in pandas mask operations, you need to use the bitwise operator `&` like this:

```
assert any(result_df.loc[result_df['colA'].str.contains('A_val') & result_df['colB'].str.contains('B_val')]['colC'] == 'C_val')
```

Comment: This gives me `E           ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar`

Comment: @Atihska that means you have more than one row in your df that matches the critera. Try my updated answer

Comment: Please check my edits on sample Dataframe I have. I get empty result so this means maybe I am not checking the way the values need to be compared as my dataframe is not empty.

Comment: an assertion will return `None` if it passes. what do you mean by "I get empty result"?

Comment: This results me empty: `result_df.loc[result_df['colA'].str.contains('A_val') & result_df['colB'].str.contains('2018-05-13')]['col_C']`

Comment: well in your df you have your columns labeled like `col_A` but then in your code you have `colA` (no underscore)

Comment: sorry, ignore typos. But I figured out. I have to convert series to string using strftime. I will post in a while the corrected answer. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Sorry about that @wpercy